# How to fix android-eclipse HelloWorld application?

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I have a problem I am not sure how to ask about. So please give me guidance, as I am a beginner with developing android apps (which is by far the most complicated, cumbersome and confusing thing to do!).

I have created a new "Hello World" project, had to do some other setup stuff (or whatever, not exactly sure what I did), and 'run' my first android application with an enumator. The emulator start, and the app "Hello World" stops immedeately with the message:

```
The application HelloWorld (process ...) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

In my eclipse window I see the following three warnings, but I am not sure if it is related to the actual problem above:

```
Could not locate '/home/alexander/opt/src/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'. This will not be added to the package.
The type ActionBarActivity is deprecated    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 3  Java Problem
The type ActionBarActivity is deprecated    MainActivity.java   /HelloWorld/src/com/example/helloworld  line 10 Java Problem
```

Here is the content of MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem? How can I even start figuring out what is wrong? Is there any other way to simpler create android applications? Or must it be really complicated, cumbersome and confusing...?

Comment: Best thing to do would be to attach a debugger to the process to see which line it's crashing on.

Comment: Use android studio instead of eclips

Comment: How to launch android studio on the ubuntu command line? Neither 'android-studio' nor 'studio' is working...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have the right SDK version. So it can't load `ActionBarActivity`.

Also `ActionBarActivity` is depricated so you might want to use `AppCompatActivity`.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

I also recommend to switch to Android Studio because it's easier to manage the SDK.

Comment: Would be great to use something else than eclipse! However: How do I start android studio?

Comment: To set up Android Studio on Linux:

1. Unpack the downloaded ZIP file into an appropriate location for your applications.
2. To launch Android Studio, navigate to the android-studio/bin/ directory in a terminal and execute studio.sh.
You may want to add android-studio/bin/ to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

Comment: When I use android-studio, can I replace all the data I have downloaded when I followed the eclipse instructions?

Comment: Im not sure what eclipse uses. I would just follow an Android Studio tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Add android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to your Buildpath
    Right click on your Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries tab --> Add External JAR --> Browse --> add android-support-v7-appcompat.jar --> ok --> Apply --> ok

    Clean and build your project and run.
```

Hopefully this will work...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your MainActivity.java with the below code

package com.example.helloworld;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

}

Comment: Please double check your code formatting. I think you need to add a few more indents to format your code correctly.